# Python - remove duplicate entries from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a big `poems.csv` file with entries like this:

```
"
this is a good poem. 
",1

"  
this is a bad poem.    
",0

"
this is a good poem. 
",1

"  
this is a bad poem.    
",0
```

and I would like to remove duplicates from it:

If the file did not have the binary classifier I could just remove duplicate lines, like this:

```
with open(data_in,'r') as in_file, open(data_out,'w') as out_file:
    seen = set() # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    for line in in_file:
        if line in seen: continue # skip duplicate
        seen.add(line)
        out_file.write(line)
```

But this would remove all classification as well. How do I remove duplicate entries  keeping `0s` and `1s`?

expected output:

```
"
this is a good poem. 
",1

"  
this is a bad poem.    
",0
```

Comment: Also, just to clarify, are two identical poems with different binary classifiers considered to be different? Your own answer seems to support this, but I would like to confirm.

Comment: no, identical entries have always the same classifier here

Comment: Could you give an example of expected input and output? It's hard to know exactly what you want to discard when you only show one row and no expected output.

Comment: I've provided an example input you can use if you wish.

Comment: thank you, your example is perfect. my data is structured the same way.

Comment: I would recommend editing that into your question. I was only able to figure out what you meant by looking at your pandas answer

Comment: @MadPhysicist done. an upvote would be nice as well

Comment: Also , i don't think you should delete your answer. It's a perfectly valid approach.

Comment: done. many thanks for your attention

Comment: Interesting. That is not what my code does. Could you explain how you decide which classifier to assign to ` this is a good poem `, given that it has both 0 and 1 as options?

Comment: you had asked me to do so. now it has only repeated entries, one for each

Comment: My point is that you have both `"this is a good poem.",1` and `"this is a good poem.",0`. How do you intend to decide which one is the duplicate and which to keep?

Comment: where do you see that? I only see `, 1` for 'this is a good poem"

Comment: I see that you removed that line ~15 hrs ago.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46616584/6

Comment: I'm not trying to make this unnecessarily confusing. I just want my answer to really work for you, which it currently might not (same problem as with your pandas code). The way I see it, you have three reasonable options: keep the classifier of the first time you encounter a poem, keep the latest classifier, or always make it 1 if that's available. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: option 1, please.

Comment: I have added an update showing how to handle all the cases :) The first option is the easiest given your current code (i.e., requires almost no modification), but not necessarily the fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add both portions of the line to the set. Assuming your "line" consists of a string and an integer (or two strings), a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) of both elements can be a valid [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) element. `tuple` is immutable, and therefore hashable, and can be added to a `set`.

Splitting the line would be much easier using the [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) class, since it would allow you to read multiline poems as a single line, etc.

```
import csv

with open(data_in, 'r', newline='') as in_file, open(data_out, 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    seen = set() # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    for row in reader:
        row = tuple(row)
        if row in seen: continue # skip duplicate
        seen.add(row)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Since you definitely have a bunch of multiline values in your file, using `newline=''` is crucial for both input and output because it delegates line splitting to the `csv` classes.

The advantage of doing it this way over using pandas or another library that preloads the entire file is that it avoids loading more than one duplicate poem into memory at one time. One copy of each poem will be retained in the `set`, but for a very large file with a lot of duplicates, this solution is much closer to optimal.

We can test with the following file:

```
"Error 404:
Your Haiku could not be found.
Try again later.", 0
"Error 404:
Your Haiku could not be found.
Try again later.", 1
"Error 404:
Your Haiku could not be found.
Try again later.", 0
"Error 404:
Your Haiku could not be found.
Try again later.", 1
```

The output is as follows:

```
"Error 404:
Your Haiku could not be found.
Try again later.", 0
"Error 404:
Your Haiku could not be found.
Try again later.", 1
```

**Note about Python 2**

The argument `newline` does not exist in the Python 2 version of [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open). This is not going to be a problem on most operating systems since line endings will be internally consistent between the input and output files. Rather than specifying `newline=''`, the Python 2 version of [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) requests that files be opened with binary mode.

**UPDATE**

You have indicated that the behavior of your own answer is not 100% correct. It appears that your data makes it a perfectly valid approach, so I am retaining the previous portion of my answer.

To be able to filter only by poem, ignoring (but preserving) the binary classifier of the first occurrence, you don't need to change much in your code:

```
import csv

with open(data_in, 'r', newline='') as in_file, open(data_out, 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    seen = set() # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] in seen: continue # skip duplicate
        seen.add(row[0])
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Since the zero classifier appears first in the file, the output for the test case above would be:

```
"Error 404:
Your Haiku could not be found.
Try again later.", 0
```

I mentioned in the comments that you can also retain either the last seen classifier or always a one if it is found. For both of these options, I would recommend using a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) (or and [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to preserve the original order of the poems) keyed by the poem, with the value being the classifier. A dictionary's keys are basically a `set`. You would also end up writing the output file after you load the entire input file.

To retain the last classifier seen:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

with open(data_in, 'r', newline='') as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    seen = OrderedDict() # map for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    for poem, classifier in reader:
        seen[poem] = classifier # Always update to get the latest classifier

with open(data_out, 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    for row in seen.items():
        writer.writerow(row)
```

`seen.items()` iterates over tuples containing the key (poem) and value (classifier), which happens to be exactly what you want to write to the file.

The output from this version will have a one classifier since that appears last in the test input above:

```
"Error 404:
Your Haiku could not be found.
Try again later.", 1
```

A similar approach will work to retain a 1 classifier if it exists:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

with open(data_in, 'r', newline='') as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    seen = OrderedDict() # map for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    for poem, classifier in reader:
        if poem not in seen or classifier == '1'
            seen[poem] = classifier

with open(data_out, 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    for row in seen.items():
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents) don't mention this at all. I think you'll be fine without `newline=''` if you are on an OS that has single-character line endings.

Comment: Note that's an empty string, not a space.

Comment: very broad and complete answer. I would upvote it twice if I could.

Comment: but mind that, like I said, `newline=""` is not accepted as an argument for python `2.X`

Comment: @outkast. I appreciate your sentiment and added a note above the update to mention Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

`pandas as pd` solved it:

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv(data_in)
clean_data = raw_data.drop_duplicates()
clean_data.to_csv(data_out)
```

Comment: Python should remove the csv library and refer to pandas (my opinion!) :)

Comment: @Anton. That comment makes no sense. The two libraries serve very different purposes. That's like telling a carpenter to get rid of his saw because he has a drill.